# ngTable execute a method with filter values

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I want to take the value of the filter input, is that possible? I have this table
[image: myTable]

with that code

```
 <td data-title="'Transaccion'" filter="{id_transaccion: 'text'}" sortable="'id_transaccion'">
    <span editable-text="pago.id_transaccion" e-name="id_transaccion" e-form="rowform" e-required="">{{pago.id_transaccion}}</span>
 </td>
```

I have the filter attr, and I tested everything trying to get the value of the field transacction of the filter, but nothing works, anyone knows how to get it?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the filters object with the method filter() of the instance of NgTableParams. If you get your table data with 'getData' instead of 'dataset' (as in the example below), everytime you change a filter value the function 'getData' will be executed and you can access your updated filter object there and make any data manipulation you want. Look at the code of the snippet below:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngTable"]);

  app.controller("demoController", demoController);

  demoController.$inject = ["NgTableParams", "$filter"];

  function demoController(NgTableParams, $filter) {
    var self = this;
    var simpleList = [{
      name: 'ww',
      age: 234,
      money: 45,
      country: 'pan'
    }, {
      name: 'xx',
      age: 24,
      money: 55,
      country: 'col'
    }, {
      name: 'yy',
      age: 454,
      money: 82,
      country: 'cr'
    }, {
      name: 'zz',
      age: 345,
      money: 34,
      country: 'mex'
    }];

    self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
      // initial filter
      filter: {
        name: "w"
      }
    }, {
      getData: getData
    });

    function getData(params) {

      /*****************************
      *       LOOK HERE!!!!!
      ******************************/
      // The filter object
      var filterObj = params.filter();
      
      self.ngTableFilters = filterObj;

      // Filtering the list using the filter object...
      var filteredList = $filter('filter')(simpleList, filterObj);

      return filteredList;
    }


  }
})();

(function() {
  "use strict";

  angular.module("myApp").run(setRunPhaseDefaults);
  setRunPhaseDefaults.$inject = ["ngTableDefaults"];

  function setRunPhaseDefaults(ngTableDefaults) {
    ngTableDefaults.params.count = 5;
    ngTableDefaults.settings.counts = [];
  }
})();
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/master/dist/ng-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/master/dist/ng-table.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" ng-controller="demoController as demo">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h3>ngTable directive</h3>
      <table ng-table="demo.tableParams" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
          <td data-title="'Name'" filter="{name: 'text'}">{{row.name}}</td>
          <td data-title="'Age'" filter="{age: 'number'}">{{row.age}}</td>
          <td data-title="'Money'" filter="{money: 'number'}">{{row.money}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h3>Filters:</h3>
      <pre>{{ demo.ngTableFilters | json }}</pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```